# Flutter: How to get a value to use for reference

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm just new to android programming. and now I have a problem in flutter / dart. So, I have a list of cards that has data showing in it, and that data is coming from the firestore database, and in the card there's also a button named "view". So I want to do is, If I click the "view" button it will show a dialog with the details of the card that I clicked. Im having a problem in getting the details and show it in a dialog. Please help :(

Here is my UI:

[My UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7I4Zj.png)

Here is my code when retrieving the data Im using a stream builder:

```
 StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
                  stream: db.collection('HELP REQUEST').snapshots(),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Column(
                          children: snapshot.data.documents
                              .map((doc) => buildItem(doc))
                              .toList());
                    } else {
                      return SizedBox();
                    }
                  })
```

and Here I put the data in a card and output it:

```
return Card(
  elevation: 5,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Name of Requestor: ${doc.data['Name_ofUser']}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        Text(
          'Help description: ${doc.data['Help_Description']}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        Text(
          'Type of help needed: ${doc.data['Help_TypeNeeded']}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        Text(
          'Help location: ${doc.data['Help_Location']}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {},
              child: Text('View'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Please help :(

Comment: Please @Lix provide the code you're using to achieve that, then it will be easier to help you

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow

Comment: I edited my post please help :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a list of Card called list

you can use @mertcan answer to display a dialog like this.

```
return Card(
elevation: 5,
  child: Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
    child: Column(
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
      children: <Widget>[
        Text(
          'Name of Requestor: ${doc.data['Name_ofUser']}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        Text(
          'Help description: ${doc.data['Help_Description']}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        Text(
          'Type of help needed: ${Text('Help description: $help')}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        Text(
          'Help location: ${doc.data['Help_Location']}',
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: 12,
        ),
        Row(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
          children: <Widget>[
            FlatButton(
              onPressed: () {
           //Note change here
             _showMydialog(doc.data)
               },
              child: Text('View'),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)


void _showMydialog(dynamic data){
showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
         children: [
             Text(Name of Requestor: ${data['Name_ofUser']),
             Text('Help description: ${doc.data['Help_Description'])
         ],
    );
  },
);
}
```

Comment: You are wellcome. please don't forget to upvote my answer

Answer (score 1):

There is a built-in function in flutter called showDialog and various dialog widgets that you can use according to your need(https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/Dialog-class.html). So it needs to look something like this

```
showDialog<void>(
  context: context,
  builder: (context) {
    return SimpleDialog(
         children: [
             Text('Name of requester: $name'),
             Text('Help description: $help')
         ],
    );
  },
);
```

Your View button click should call this function.

Comment: Yes sir, but I'm having a problem getting that data to show it in the dialog box :(